Inverse of hazard function
I want to know $t$ based on the output of the hazard function $\lambda(t)$. Is it possible to numerically solve the inverse of the hazard function as defined as:
$\lambda(t)=\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}$
where $f(t)$ is the probability density function and $S(t)$ the survival function. After searching on this forum, I found that the inverse of $S(t)$ can be numerically solved, but the inverse of $f(t)$ provides one, two, or zero solutions.
I want to be able to solve this for both a Weibull and Kaplan-Meier model.
A simple workaround is to find the closest value when generating a lot of samples, but I was looking for a more elegant solution. Solutions with examples in Python are appreciated!

Unless some special assumptions are made, it is not generally possible to determine the time value from the hazard function, since the latter can take on any values over time.  In particular, a common model form uses constant hazard, leading to an exponentially distributed time-to-failure.  In this case all time values would have the same hazard rate.
The reason that the distribution function $F$ and the survival function $S$ each have an inverse (for a continuous time-to-failure) is that they are monotonically increasing/decreasing functions resectively.  The hazard function does not have this restriction and in general it is not invertible.

In particular, for the Kaplan-Meier model mentioned by the OP, the hazard is identically 0 between event times. If the OP wants to assume a Weibull distribution other than the limiting case of the constant-hazard exponential, there is a hazard as a function of time that could be inverted, as Weibull has a monotone hazard function in time. What's not clear from the OP is how an estimate of instantaneous hazard would be obtained from usual survival data without already estimating the cumulative hazard/survival curve. (+1)

Thanks, the goal of this was that I have a mathematical problem where $\lambda(t) = function$ where we know the hazard rate, the value of the function, but t is unknown. What I've done now is to use the Newton-Raphson root-finding algorithm to find t.
